# A lost and confused newbie - installation

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to Linux, Ubuntu, and ROS.  From the installation page:

I ran this in the terminal, and there were no problems:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main" > /etc/apt  /sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

And no problems with this:
sudo apt-get update

I ran this a couple of times in the terminal:
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full
and the terminal gave this:
Reading package list...  Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...  Done
ros-fuerte-desktop-full is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.

Now what?  Remember, I am clueless about the whole thing.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33795/a-lost-and-confused-newbie---installation/) by [kentoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2368/kentoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That means you've completed the installation. Good start!

[The tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) are the thing to do next.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3